# Qfield online data collection

Tags: qfield

Qfield comes with a demonstration Beekeeping package installed. This package allows users to add new points and data that are updated online. Does anyone know of a tutorial that shows how this is done? I have a multi-user project for field data collection but I can only update the data offline using Qsync. In a multi-user environment this is time consuming and difficult and it would be much easier if I knew how to update data online.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the demo **offline_bees.qgs** project that is already installed in QField, I'm not sure that the data is online, it looks like it is stored in a GPKG file.

But you can find here : https://github.com/opengisch/QField/tree/master/resources/demo_projects an other demo project called **online_survey** which is online (the data is displayed here: http://demo.qfield.org/websig/lizmap/www/index.php/view/map/) that uses a PostGIS connection:

[image]

Basically, if you want to work with online data, you have several options (see here the list of supported formats : https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/dataformat.html) but I would say that the most common would be a PostGIS connection or a WFS if you have a server that can return the data in this format.

Comment: thanks for your response. I will read through the links that you sent me.

Comment: You are correct the online project I was referring to is the online_survey. Do you know of any tutorials that explain how this was done?

Comment: Use **Layer > Add Layer > Add PostGIS Layer** to open a PostGIS connection in QGIS. Then style your project and publish it following the QField documentation : https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/index.html , https://qfield.org/docs/qfieldsync/index.html?highlight=postgis